# m.Custom scrollbar not working in RTL Mode

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar, right-to-left, mcustomscrollbar

I have made a website ( static for just now ) and I have used scroll bar for displaying recent post in a widget it has vertical and horizontal scrollbar both.
The base of the website is bootstrap 4.1.3 and all the thing works fine in ltr mode.

But when I converted it to rtl, the scrollbar ( i.e. m.customscrollbar )  default position stick to the left side instead of right by default and it does not change.

**Here is my js code**

```
$("selector").mCustomScrollbar({
    axis:"yx", // vertical and horizontal scrollbar
    autoHideScrollbar:true
});
```

**NOTE:-** I have applied this class **(at the body tag)** to make it rtl.

```
.rtl {
    text-align: right;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

I have already used ***dir="rtl"*** attribute to make it rtl but still it does`nt work.

***UPDATE:***

When I apply jquery 2.1.3 or 1.11.1 it works but when I apply 3.1.1 or 3.3.1 it does`nt works.

Here is working examples:-

with jquery 1.11.1 - [example 1](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xyQRBj)   (working)

with jquery 2.1.3 - [example 2](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rqQRLp)    (working)

with jquery 3.3.1 - [example 3](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XxyGjE)    (not working)

Including your example it does`nt work on jquery 3.3.1

Comment: could you post your html? this example works with your code. https://codepen.io/peker-ercan/pen/vVQmVb

Comment: @ErcanPeker does it works with jquery 3.1.1